# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 29

Tags: php, html

I am still pretty new at PHP and I am trying to incorporate html into my page, I keeping getting the following error and I cannot seem to figure it out.

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\Hosting\11304243\html\cnghldb\cnghlplayerinfo.php on line 29" Line 29 is the second line in the code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerInfo))
{
Print "<body>";
Print "<div align="left">";
Print "<h2><strong>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</strong></h2><br>";
Print "table width="710" border="0">;
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td width="188"<strong>Birthdate:</strong>" ".$row['DOB']."</td><br>";
Print "<td width="225"<strong>Nation:</strong></td>" ".$row['Nation']."</td><br>";
Print "<td width=" rowspan="8"><div align="center"><img src=\"http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/".$iPlayerID.".jpg\">";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>" ;
Print '<td><strong>"Position:</strong> ".$row['Position']. </td>"<br>';
Print '<td><strong>"CNGHL Team:</strong> ".$row['CNGHLRights']. </td>"<br>';
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>Height:</strong> ".$row['Height']. </td>"<br>";  
Print "<td><strong>Weight:</strong> ".$row['Weight']. </td>"<br>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>NHL Team:</strong> ".$row['Team']. </td>"<br>";
Print "<td><&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>Draft Position:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftPOS'].</td>"<br>";
Print "<td><strong>Draft Year:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftYR'].</td>"<br>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftTEAM'].<td>"<br>";
Print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print '<td height="88">&nbsp;</td>';
Print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print '<tr>';
Print '<td height="58">&nbsp;</td>';
Print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "</table>";
Print "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
Print '<p><img src="http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/pageimages/statistics.gif" width="190" height="18" /></p>';
```

Comment: There's probably an unclosed quote somewhere before this code.

Comment: Pick a quote style and be consistent.  If you need double quotes in your strings, either escape all other double quotes or  use single quotes to surround your strings.

Comment: look up php here doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: It's hight time for you to read [*PHP Strings*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Your answer is hidden in your question itself. Watch the colors.

Comment: Just posting it here shows the some of the errors

Comment: This way of coding is very bad.

Comment: And we are not even commenting on using tables for layout. And if there is more than one result there will be more than one body tag. Quite amazing how OP decided to ignore all the suggestions for duplicate answers on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of problem in your code. You are not using double quote and single quote properly. I removed errors here:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerInfo))
{
Print "<body>";
Print "<div align='left'>";
Print "<h2><strong>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</strong></h2><br>";
Print "table width='710' border='0'>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td width='188'<strong>Birthdate:</strong> ".$row['DOB']."</td><br>";
Print "<td width='225'<strong>Nation:</strong></td> ".$row['Nation']."</td><br>";
Print "<td width='' rowspan='8'><div align='center'><img src=\"http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/".$iPlayerID.".jpg\">";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>" ;
Print '<td><strong>Position:</strong> '.$row['Position']. '</td><br>';
Print '<td><strong>"CNGHL Team:</strong> '.$row['CNGHLRights']. '</td><br>';
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>Height:</strong> ".$row['Height']. "</td><br>";  
Print "<td><strong>Weight:</strong> ".$row['Weight']. "</td><br>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>NHL Team:</strong> ".$row['Team']. "</td><br>";
Print "<td><&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>Draft Position:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftPOS']."</td><br>";
Print "<td><strong>Draft Year:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftYR']."</td><br>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftTEAM']."<td><br>";
Print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "<tr>";
Print '<td height="88">&nbsp;</td>';
Print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print '<tr>';
Print '<td height="58">&nbsp;</td>';
Print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "</table>";
Print "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
Print '<p><img src="http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/pageimages/statistics.gif" width="190" height="18" /></p>';
}
```

Comment: But did not fix the underlying poor premise

Comment: Thanks that was a big help!

Answer (score 0):

change double quotes inside to single one like this :

Current `Print "<div align="left">";`
New will be `Print "<div align='left'>";`

Same for all your syntax erros.

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes are not at the right place.

Please replace

`Print "<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftTEAM'].<td>"<br>";`

By

`Print "<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftTEAM']."<td><br>";`

Also, please remove the double quotes inside the HTML tags like:

`Print "<td width="188"<strong>Birthdate:</strong>" ".$row['DOB']."</td><br>";`

Should be:

`Print "<td width='188'<strong>Birthdate:</strong>" ".$row['DOB']."</td><br>";`

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what  Crackertastic is referring to:

```
 Print "<div align="left">"
```

should look like one of the following

```
 Print "<div align='left'>"
 Print "<div align=\"left\">"
 Print '<div align="left">'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Print "<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftTEAM'].<td>"<br>";
```

with

```
Print "<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftTEAM']."<td><br>";
```

in line number 29

```
* <td> should be inside quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your fix

`Print "<div align=\"left\">";`

Comment: @mplungjan - it depends on how the syntax is written.. a better and faster approach would be `Print '<div align="left">';`

Comment: An even better one would be heredoc and I personally favour echo of the var without any other php in the html

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE.

Notepad++ picked it up

```
 Print "<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong> ".$row['CNDraftTEAM'].<td>"<br>";
```

Got the quote in the wrong place

Hence the error message

Comment: And not the `Print "table width="710" border="0">;` that the syntax highlighter here at SO picked up first?

Comment: Yes. had notepad++. for meCTRL A etc was quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, you have used multiple times of double quotes in a print()

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerInfo))
    {

    Print '<body>';
    Print '<div align="left">';
    Print '<h2><strong>'.$row["FirstName"].' '.$row["LastName"].'</strong></h2><br>';
    Print '<table width="710" border="0">';
    Print '<tr>';
    Print '<td width="188"><strong>Birthdate:</strong>'.$row["DOB"].'</td><br>';
    Print '<td width="225"><strong>Nation:</strong></td>'.$row["Nation"].'</td><br>';
    Print '<td width="" rowspan="8"><div align="center"><img                 src="http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/'.$iPlayerID.'.jpg">';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '<tr>' ;
    Print '<td><strong>Position:</strong>'.$row["Position"].'</td><br>';
    Print '<td><strong>CNGHL Team:</strong> '.$row["CNGHLRights"].'</td><br>';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '<tr>';
    Print '<td><strong>Height:</strong>'.$row["Height"].'</td><br>';  
    Print '<td><strong>Weight:</strong>'.$row["Weight"].'</td><br>';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '<tr>';
    Print '<td><strong>NHL Team:</strong>'.$row["Team"].'</td><br>';
    Print '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '<tr>';
    Print '<td><strong>Draft Position:</strong>'.$row["CNDraftPOS"].'</td><br>';
    Print '<td><strong>Draft Year:</strong>'.$row["CNDraftYR"].'</td><br>';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '<tr>';
    Print '<td><strong>Drafted By:</strong>'.$row["CNDraftTEAM"].'<td><br>';
    Print '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '<tr>';
    Print '<td height="88">&nbsp;</td>';
    Print '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '<tr>';
    Print '<td height="58">&nbsp;</td>';
    Print '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    Print '</tr>';
    Print '</table>';
    Print '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
    Print '<p><img src="http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/pageimages/statistics.gif"         width="190" height="18" /></p>';

    }
```